# MySQL: Display Password as *******

Tags: mysql, database, password-protection

I'm creating a table where a password needs to be stored, but when displayed I don't want the password to be shown, I want asterisks to be displayed.

For example, if the password is abc123, when selected I want it to display *******.

Is this done when creating the column for the table, or is it done when inserting the password value into the password column?

I've read into encrypting, which I plan on doing, but it displays the encrypted value when selected which is don't want.

Any help will be great thanks!

Comment: `select username, '********' as password from youraccounts;`. but its also slightly odd at all to be accessing this data

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Just use `password_hash` to store them

Comment: I'm new to creating databases so I felt it would be best to have passwords encrypted and displayed by asterisks. This is not a product just a practice run in creating databases. Tips are always great so thank you all! @DarkBee

Comment: Encrypted password are just the way to go. Even if the hacker obtains the database it would be a struggle to decrypt them if you use `password_hash` just don't use old encrypting methods like `md5` or `sha1`. Using the `password_hash` also allows you to renew the hash of the user just by updating the password field when the user logs in